# InternalSyntheticLambda in Crash report

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I got following crash report:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at com.myapp.actions.SellAction.getAction (SellAction.java:16)
  at com.myapp.handler.SellHandler.sell (SellHandler.java:169)
  at com.myapp.main.MyActivity.sell (MyActivity.java:537)
  at com.myapp.main.Fragment2.lambda$onCreateView$0 (Fragment2.java:31)
  at com.myapp.main.Fragment1$$InternalSyntheticLambda$1$c14fd7a0fe0c17e220e277448d1b71579f8038a9784d642f5a2e5b6a00f377eb$2.onClick$bridge (Fragment1.java)
  at android.view.View.performClick (View.java:7862)
  at android.widget.TextView.performClick (TextView.java:15004)
  at android.view.View.performClickInternal (View.java:7831)
  at android.view.View.access$3600 (View.java:879)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:29359)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:883)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:100)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:237)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8167)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:496)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

The code from `Fragment2.lambda$onCreateView$0 (Fragment2.java:31)` to `SellAction.getAction` is a valid stacktrace in my code. But usually (I don't see how this is possible) the Fragment1 (`Fragment1$$InternalSyntheticLambda$1$c14fd7a0fe0c17e220e277448d1b71579f8038a9784d642f5a2e5b6a00f377eb$2.onClick$bridge (Fragment1.java)`) has nothing to do with that code and I have no idea how it appears there. I don't know if that has something to do with the `InternalSyntheticLambda`. But I do not find anything about that on the internet (10 search results at google). Does anyone here has an idea what that is or how that can happen?

Comment: Are you using desugaring?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- not explicitly as far as I know. Do I have to activate that in ProGuard?

Comment: I am getting the same set of crashes. It's crashing in a code base which has nothing to do with the current screen. @L3n95 were you able to solve this?

Comment: @UdayadityaBarua Unfortunately not. Are you using Data binding?

Comment: @L3n95 I am using viewbinding.

Comment: @UdayadityaBarua I am too. I could imagine that it is a problem with this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some handler or listener is leaking.

Try to look through all the call chain between

```
at com.myapp.actions.SellAction.getAction (SellAction.java:16)
```

and

```
at com.myapp.main.Fragment2.lambda$onCreateView$0 (Fragment2.java:31)
```

There might be view or some other object that is set up with listener which is not dropped correctly on view destroy. Special attention to  `Fragment2#onCreateView` line 31.